# cakephp - order being ignored when paginating

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a controller for Properties which I'm trying to paginate.

In my search action I'm doing:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 3);
$this->set('properties', $this->Paginator->paginate('Property', array('Property.archived'=>0), array('price')));
```

and it's picking up the settings for limit and the conditions, but not the order. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Been reading the pagination page on the manual but can't spot what my problem is. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: can anyone help me out. Is there any possible reason this doesn't work. It's what it says to do in the manual :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your controller.

```
$this->paginate = array('limit' => 3, 'order' => array('asc' => 'Property.price'));
$this->set('properties', $this->Paginator->paginate('Property', array('Property.archived'=>0)));
```

Thanks..!